# Is there a formula that allows you to square a number without multiplying the number by itself?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a formula that allows you to square a number without multiplying the number by itself?

While a formula like this may not be practical for small numbers, for large numbers it may be much quicker to use a formula rather than multiplying the number by itself.

Comment: The standard multiplication algorithm is pretty darn fast. There is a reason it is so prolific.

Comment: What do you think the formula will tell you to do? For example, I immediately thought of  $\text{square}(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @Robert, perhaps you can give an example?  IS there a problem you are working on where multiplying the number by itself is prohibitive?

Comment: The formula would mainly make the process quicker if you are working by hand and trying to multiply an extremely large number by itself (say $74837583^2$ or a similarly large number or a number with many decimal values), it might make it easier than doing the long multiplication. Maybe it could be derived by thinking of the list of squares as a sequence of numbers

Comment: Perhaps you can look up "fast" multiplication methods that are typically not taught in school, like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#:~:text=The%20Karatsuba%20algorithm%20was%20the,faster%2C%20for%20sufficiently%20large%20n.)

Comment: yes there is but it's not fast enough when dealing with large numbers. If you wanted to square $4$, you would just need to add $1+3+5+7$ to get $4^2=16$. Now suppose you want to square the following number $123456791011121314151617181920$. You would need the same number of additions.

Comment: @Arthur: the standard multiplication algorithm is slow when the numbers get big. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Computational_complexity_of_multiplication

Comment: The faster algorithms only apply for numbers that big that noone would multiply them by hand anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one example of how you can break the problem into a sum of smaller squares.
$$(74837583)^2 = (74830000+7583)^2 = (7483)^2\times 10^8 + 2\times 7483 \times 7583 \times 10^4 + (7583)^2.$$

In this way, you do a series of four digit multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the method for [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#2k-ary_method) based on the binary expansion of the number to square. It will only involve additions, with logarithmic complexity.

For example:

- $7^2 = 7 + (7+7) + ((7+7)+(7+7))$
- $5^2 = 5 + ((5+5)+(5+5))$